# Material Table React Custom Row Rendering

Tags: reactjs, material-table

**How to render custom nodes from data in Material Table react**
( Ex: I want to show rows only with particular filed value>0)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to show a row in the table based on your condition. You can add that same condition while preparing the data.

I have attached a sandbox for rendering the same. I took a boolean value to display the row or not in the table.
Something like this.

```
<>
  {row?.showValue && (
    <TableRow
      key={row.name}
      sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
    >
      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
        {row['property']}
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  )}
</>;
```

[image: Edit BasicTable Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: no i am asking in MaterialTable i dont want to show table with some particular filed value less than a number (Ex: if there is table with list of student details and marks i want to display table with only marks greater than some marks) and its in MaterialTable not in normal Table

Comment: Maybe you can filter out the data before rendering the table. Just prepare the data how you wanna render it on Mui table.